# Fourier transform of $f(x)=1/x$

Tags: fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I would like to compute the Fourier transform for the function:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1/x&, x\in [a,b] \\ 0,& x \notin [a,b]\end{cases}
\end{equation}
but I cannot do the integral:

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{x}dx
\end{equation}
I do know that the improper integral of this Fourier transform can be computed as a principal value (PV) integral but I cannot find the result in a closed form.

Comment: @tired: The last integral is a value of an incomplete $\Gamma$ function, there is no way of getting a "nicer" form for generic values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: However, you may write your function as $\frac{1}{x}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}(x)$, hence the Fourier transform of $f$ is given by the convolution of two well-known Fourier transforms.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio This Fourier transform is part of the computation of the convolution of $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=1-|x|$ where $g$ is limited between $[-1,1]$. While in the computation I had to deal with this integral. What do you mean to write it down as the convolution of two well known Fourier transforms?

Comment: Why not to compute the convolution between $\sin x$ and $(1-|x|)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(x)$ through the definition $$ (f * g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) g(x-y)\,dy $$?

Comment: I simply got that the convolution between $\sin x$ and $(1-|x|)$ supported over $[-1,1]$ is $ 4\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sin x.$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But that is what I try to do. I tried to go through the definition but I cannot make it to the end since I end up with Fourier transform above.. If I may, could you show me how did you compute it?

Comment: There is no Fourier transform involved in the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)g(x-y)\,dy,$$ it is just the integral of a sine function multiplied by a scaled-and-translated absolute value function. You do not need Fourier transforms to compute it. Fourier transforms just provide an alternative way to accomplish such a task.

Comment: And by the way, the Fourier transform of $(1-|x|)$ supported over $[-1,1]$ is a multiple of $\left(\frac{\sin s}{s}\right)^2$ while the Fourier transform of $\sin x$ is the difference of two Dirac delta functions, so I do not see how the present question comes from the original one.

Comment: What I did is: \begin{equation} (f*g)(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x+1}(1-|x-y|)\frac{siny}{y}dy =\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\frac{siny}{y}dy+\int_{x-1}^{x+1}|x-y|\frac{siny}{y}dy \end{equation}  The first of these two integrals can be written as: \begin{equation} I_1=\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\frac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2iy}dy \end{equation} and that is the point where is think that I can use the Fourier transform of $f(x)=1/x$ limited at $[x-1,x+1]$. Is that wrong? Is there another way? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Wasn't one of the functions simply $\sin x$? Where the term $\frac{\sin y}{y}$ comes from?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I am terribly sorry, I made a typo on my comment above. Sorry to put you through all this, I meant the convolution of $f(x)=\sin x/x$ and $g(x)=1-|x|$.. If you do not help me furthermore, I do understand it.